# UINavigationbar background color issue setTintColor in iPad 6.0

Tags: ios, ipad, ios5, ios6, ios-simulator

Hi I am new with iPad Development, I am developing one app which is Compatible for iPad 5.1 Simulator and iPad 6.0 Simulator

I did something Like in 5.1 SDK

```
[self.navigationBar setTintColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:0.247f green:.301f blue:0.325f alpha:1.0f]];
```

same code is not working with iPad 6.0 Simulator,

Thanks in Advance!

Comment: How you create the navigationBar? Through code or through xib or storyboard?

Comment: Thank Wolvorin I am creating navigationBar through Code

Comment: ok so you use `UINavigationBar` object right then give a try to `navigationBar.tintColor` as this is working for me :)

Comment: If possible will you please put the code how you add the navigationBar ?

Comment: navigationBar.tintColor  not working

Comment: is this working ?[self.navigationControl.navigationBar setBackgroundColor:[UIColor redColor]];

Comment: Thanks Madhumitha it's not working

Comment: print the reference of self.navigatiobar using NSLog.

Comment: try to set image for navigationbar.Refer this link [link](http://www.appcoda.com/customize-navigation-bar-back-butto/) it may help you.

Comment: Thanks Madhumitha for answer but I have to use color why to increase resources

Comment: have print reference of self.navigationbar?

Comment: check here. Its working...

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18929864/how-do-i-change-the-navigation-bar-color-in-ios-7

Answer (score 1):

For ios 6.0 you can make use of UIAppearance frame work and set the color. Use `[[UINavigationBar appearance] setTintColor:color];` in your AppDelegate didFinishLaunchingWithOptions.

Answer (score 0):

try this code and replace 0 with your value

```
self.navigationController.navigationBar.tintColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:(0/255.0) green:(0/255.0) blue:(0/255.0) alpha:1];
```